# no stdout and no update in hive when using KafkaUtils.createDirectStream

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

i want to show logs in spark streaming, but nothing. maybe need helps.

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("DirectKafka")
sparkConf.setMaster("yarn-client") //also try local[*]
  //    sparkConf.set("spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition", "5")
  //    sparkConf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")

val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))
val topicsSet = Set("topic")
val kafkaParams = Map[String, String](
    "metadata.broker.list" -> "ip1:9092,ip2:9092",
    "group.id" -> "test0107",
    "auto.offset.reset" -> "smallest"
  )

val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream()
 messages.foreachRDD{rdd =>
        val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(rdd.sparkContext.getConf).getOrCreate()
        import spark.implicits._
        val df = spark.read.json(rdd.map(_._2))
        print(df.count()) //no stdout
        df.createOrReplaceTempView("words")
        val wc = spark.sql("select count(1) as id  from words ")
         wc.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).insertInto("test.rt_test") //no update in hive 
         wc.show()  //no stdout
      }
```

Only outputs:

> 18/01/07 13:28:30 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Added jobs for time
>   1515302910000 ms 18/01/07 13:28:32 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Added
>   jobs for time 1515302912000 ms

Comment: Are you running this locally or in a cluster environment?

Comment: both  locally or in a cluster

Comment: Have you started `ssc`? Looks like you have given the INFOs by it's not in the code posted (which is kind of confusing). Does this compile?! Where do you specify the topic(s) to read records from (should've been in `KafkaUtils.createDirectStream()`)?